# Rounded Box around Activity Indicator with "Loading" Text

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I know how to make an activity indicator with a simple square background, but there is no padding at all, and I don't know how to get the word "loading" to display like this.

[image]

Does anyone know how this is accomplished? I've looked online and can't seem to find anything. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use some custom component, you can use [MBProgressHUD](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mbprogresshud). Here is the [source code](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) for that.

[image]

If you want to make it yourself, you can check their source code to see how they have implemented this and you can follow a similar approach for your code. Basically that will involve subclassing `UIView` and drawing the activity indicator and label in `drawRect` method.

Answer (score 1):

The black background is `UIImageView`. So in your viewController where you want to display this:

```
[self.view UIImageView]; //Set proper frame for the UIImageView so that it comes in the centre.
```

On that image view, add an activity indicator and a label which says "loading".

I think this will give you what you want.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

switch (self.maskType) {

    case SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack: {
        [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5] set];
        CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
        break;
    }

    case SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient: {

        size_t          locationsCount = 2;
        CGFloat         locations[2]   = {0.0f, 1.0f};
        CGFloat         colors[8]      = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.75f};
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace     = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef   gradient       = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, locations, locationsCount);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height    / 2);
        float   radius = MIN(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height) ;
        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, center, 0, center, radius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);

        break;
      }
   }
 }
+ (void)showWithStatus:(NSString *)status {
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:status   networkIndicator:SVProgressHUDShowNetworkIndicator];
}

  + (void)showInView:(UIView *)view status:(NSString *)string {

 [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:string maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeNone    networkIndicator:SVProgressHUDShowNetworkIndicator];
```

}

```
  - (void)showWithStatus:(NSString *)string maskType:(SVProgressHUDMaskType)hudMaskType   networkIndicator:(BOOL)show {

self.fadeOutTimer = nil;

if (self.showNetworkIndicator)
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

self.showNetworkIndicator = show;

if (self.showNetworkIndicator)
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

self.imageView.hidden = YES;
self.maskType         = hudMaskType;

[self setStatus:string];
[self.spinnerView startAnimating];

if (self.maskType != SVProgressHUDMaskTypeNone) {
    self.overlayWindow.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
} else {
    self.overlayWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

[self.overlayWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[self positionHUD:nil];

if (self.alpha != 1) {
    [self registerNotifications];
    self.hudView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.hudView.transform, 1.3, 1.3);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         self.hudView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.hudView.transform, 1 / 1.3, 1 / 1.3);
                         self.alpha             = 1;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
}

[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

}